# Show all SSRS data on opening report then hide data to single page

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tabular report that has Show/Hide grouping on the rows. The end user wants all data displayed when first running the report, which is no problem. It covers roughly 3 or 4 pages. Can I make so that if I hide all the data, it then refreshes to show the "rolled" up table on a single page rather than split across multiple pages?

Comment: Did you put a `toggle` to show/hide grouping rows? So your user wants the tablix be expanded when first running, right?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta if you mean by toggle the little + sign, then yes I do. Correct, expanded on opening when first run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the report all rolled up when first run. Expanding from that state seems to keep the report on a single page plus I can roll it back up to a single page (although probably simpler to just re-run it).

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties window of the cells you are toggling display.

[image]

In the `InitialToggleState` property select `False`, it will show all data when you running the report initially.

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's only when it is first run isn't it?

Comment: When you run the report it will show all data, if you press the `+` sign it will hide it.

Comment: yes that is correct. However, if the report covers multiple pages, it only hides the data on a specific page. I want to hide all data such that the first page would then show just the rolled up summary of all the data, not just the data that was on the front page of the report.

Comment: In that case an option could be split your data in several tablix and put page breaks. For each table put a toggle, since toggle control only hide/show data on the page where the toggle item is placed.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll have a try with page breaks and see how I get on. Appreciate the help.